# Show that when $p$ is a principal type, it must contain the formula that implies it

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

In my model theory lecture course, a partial type $p$ is defined to be principal when there is some $ϕ$ such that $T \models ∃vϕ(v)$ (for any n-place variable $V$) and for any $ψ ∈ p$, $T \models ∀v(ϕ(v) → ψ(v))$.

[and we define a partial type of a theory $T$ in variables $x$ to be a satisfiable set $P$ of
formulas in the variables $x$, containing $T$ and closed under logical deduction.]

I'm asked to show that when $p$ is a principal (complete) type, the formula $ϕ$ which features in the definition above must be in $p$.

It's clear that since $T \models ∃vϕ(v)$, and $p$ must be closed under logical deduction, that $∃vϕ(v) \in p$ , but I don't see how it follows that $ϕ(v) \in p$, which is what I'm being asked to prove.

Any suggestions you could give me would very much be appreciated.

Comment: Is the principal type $p$ in question supposed to be complete?  Otherwise this isn't true.  (This definition of "principal type" is also quite weird, and I would consider it nonstandard when applied to incomplete types.)

Comment: @EricWofsey yes it should be, you're right - in our course if we just say 'type' we mean a complete one (I'm not sure how standard this is).

Comment: @yoasdf That last bit is standard, but it can get confusing when you are also talking about partial types.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment this question only makes sense for complete types. So let $p$ be a principal type, with principal formula $φ \in F_n$. Since p is complete, $φ \not\in p \implies ¬φ \in p$. Add new constant symbols $c = (c_1, c_2, ..., c_n)$. The principality condition gives us that $T \cup \{φ(c)\} \models ψ(c)$ for all $ψ(x) \in p$, and so $T \cup \{φ(c)\} \models ¬φ(c)$. It follows that $T \models ¬φ(c)$, and therefore $T \models ¬\exists x φ(x)$. This contradicts the fact that $φ$ is realised in all models of T, i.e. $Τ \models \exists x φ(x)$. Thus $φ \in p$.